# How to write a good Wait() function in C++

Tags: c++, sleep

I am writing a wrapper around the C++ API of a programme, which needs to connect to a network.  I want my own Connect() function to wait for 2 seconds or less, and continue if no connection is established. What I was thinking of is simply using `Sleep(...)` and checking again, but this doesn't work:

```
class MyWrapperClass 
{
    IClient* client;

    bool MyWrapperClass::Connect()
    {
        client->Connect();
        int i = 0;
        while (i++ < 20 && !client->IsConnected())
            Sleep(100); /* Sleep for 0.1 s to give client time to connect (DOESN'T HAPPEN) */ 

        return client->IsConnected();
    }
}
```

I am assuming that this fails (i.e. no connection is established) because the thread as a whole stops, including the `IClient::Connect()` method. I have no access to this method, so I cannot verify whether this starts any other threads or anything.

Is there a better way to have a function wait for a short while *without* blocking anything?

**Edit:**

To complicate matters consider the following: the programme *has to* be compiled with `/clr` as the API demands this (so `std::thread` cannot be used) AND `IClient` cannot be an unmanaged class (i.e. `IClient^ client = gcnew IClient()` is not legal), as the class contains unmanaged stuff. Neither is in my power to alter, as it is demanded by the API.

Comment: Start it in another thread and see if it's done after two seconds.

Comment: `because the thread as a whole stops, including the IClient::Connect() method` - I don't think so, since if `Connect` was on the same thread, you wouldn't have reached till `IClient::IsConnected`, which leads me to think that `IClient::Connect` is asynchronous so `Sleep` shouldn't block the connecting. Are you sure it doesn't sleep that long? Have you measured it?

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn, The Windows API equivalent of `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(x));`.

Comment: @legends2k: I agree it seems like it should be on a different thread indeed. But normally it connects within 0.2 s, generally less, and even when I have it sleep for 10 seconds in this way, it doesn't want to connect.

Comment: The suggestion by @chris would probably work actually, but I don't manage to implement this (see Edit). But the problem I'm running into may be beyond the scope of this question; should I post this as a new question?

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out you can't wait without blocking. Blocking IS the entire point of waiting.

I would look carefully af IClient and read *any* documentation to ensure there is no function that lets you do this asynchronously.

If you have no luck, then you are left with doing a loop with sleep in you code. If you can use c++11 then Chris gave a good suggetion. Otherwise you are left with whatever your OS gives you. On a POSIX system (unix) you could try usleep() or nanosleep() to give you shorter sleep than sleep() see http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect without switching to another thread you can use system-specific options for that. For example [setsockopt() for SO_RCVTIMEO](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) option before connect will help you on linux. You can try to find a way to pass a preconfigured socket to the library in question.